# how to translate a placeholder

Tags: html, json, placeholder, translate

I am having issues trying to translate my placeholder.

```
<template id="dynamicTemplate">
</template>

<select id="languageSwitch">
    <option value="nl">Nederlands</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="voornaam" data-translate="homepage.voornaam" id="voornaam"  required>
<input type="text" placeholder="achternaam" id="achternaam" required>
```

I am using a js that works with buttons and text but this placeholder I can't seem to fix.

this is the js:

```js
       //vertaling
var initialLanguage = "en";

var translations = {
    homepage: { 
voornaam: {
            "nl":"voornaam",
            "en": "First Name"
        },
```

this is the code i use for CSS:

```
    /* vertaling test */
[data-translate] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

[data-translate][translated] {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Does anyone know where I can put the data-translate to make the code work ? School wants me to use the JS translations.

Greetings and thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I'd pick inputs with the placeholder by js, check their data-translate attribute, and if it exists, copy the value there on page load

Comment: "I am using a js" - Please [edit] the question and include this js.

Comment: The JS that you show does not nothing besides defining some variables. There must be more. Where are the parts that make it "... work with buttons and text"? Show that, and also how you tried to make it work with placeholders.

Comment: yes i am a first year student. sorry for not complety post every code piece.

Comment: It's probably a plugin -- some external script file ex. `<script src='translate.js'></script>`

Comment: plugin works good. i succesfully translated a button and a h3 text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="voornaam" data-translate="homepage.voornaam" id="voornaam"  required>
```

using label instead of a place holder. :

```
<label data-translate="homepage.voornaam">Voornaam</label>
<input id="voornaam" required>
```